# Is it good practice to allow user to upload files to app_code folder?

Tags: asp.net

Recently I have seen a web application developed in ASP.Net by someone in which user is allowed to upload an excel file from the web page, which is stored in app_code folder. Then this file is read and stored into database and deleted from the folder after load. So my question is, is it correct way to store user uploaded files in app_code folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not allow users to upload *anything* to app_code.  Class files uploaded to the app_code folder are automatically compiled and referenced throughout the application.  It would be a huge security hole to let users upload files to there.

Comment: The file is stored temporarily(10 to 15 secs) in the folder and is deleted immediately once the data load is done. Will it still cause security issues? If yes what would be the better place to store the user uploaded files?

Comment: again, anything uploaded to the app_code folder is compiled and *immediately* referenced throughout the project.  It is a massive security hole to allow users to upload arbitrary files to app_code.  You're better off creating a file named something like "Uploads", and referencing it using `Server.MapPath("~/Uploads")`.  Whatever approach you take, do *not* allow users to upload into app_code.

Answer (score 1):

Typically all user-generated content should stay out of the application path. Instead, create a virtual folder in IIS, pointing to some dedicated file storage location, and upload to that folder. This way when you're pushing updates to your app you don't have to worry about messing with uploaded content.